# Double or float data type in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, adobe

What data type do I use in flex (flash builder) to create a "double" or "float" data type. I need the numbers after a decimal point. (i.e. prices)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The datatype you are looking for is `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

See all Flex datatypes here.
[Flex Data Type Descriptions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_11.html)